# Missing index.html and folders structure?

Tags: r, bookdown

1. After using `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")` in RStudio/Windows the index file is not being generated.  As the first chapter is `#preface` (in "index.rmd"), the file being generated is preface.html.  The consequence is that it is not working in GitHub. Am I missing something?
2. How should be the settings in yaml files in order to keep the .rmd (source files of the book) in a subfolder of my R projects and generate the book in another folder? I am trying to have the bookdowm integrated in my research folder structure.

Thanks for this amazing package!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, my problem is that I had written two chapters in the index file.  After removing the "# About the author" part, the index.html file came back.